# Is this a correct approach for Spacekings problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

One of the solutions for SpaceKings problem asked in a few companies.

**Statement** :

Asha and Amar are playing SpaceKings a video game. It is a two-player game where the second player is the helper. Asha needs your help maximizing her gold while playing her favorite game. Both are facing N aliens. Asha and Amar are both at a single location and the aliens are lined up in front of them. Asha and Amar take turns shooting the aliens, and she goes first. During her turn, Asha may choose any alien to shoot at (this means Asha may choose to skip a turn). During his turn, Amar always shoots the alien closest to him to help Asha maximize her gold. Asha and Amar can not shoot dead aliens.

If Asha shoots at an alien, its hit points are reduced by P. If Amar shoots at an alien, its hit points are reduced by Q. If an alien’s hit points go below 1, it is killed. The ith alien starts with Hi hit points. Asha is awarded Gi gold if her shot kills the ith alien, but none if Amar’s shot kills it. What is the maximum amount of gold Asha can obtain?

Input:

Each case begins with one line containing three space-separated integers representing P, Q and N. N lines then follow, with the ith line containing two space-separated integers representing Hi and Gi. The aliens are given in the order of their distance from Asha and Amar. In other words, Amar will shoot at the ith alien only if all aliens < i are dead.

Output - The maximum amount of gold that Asha can get

Input

20 60 3

80 100

80 200

120 300

Output - 500

Explanation:
Asha should give up the first alien. During her first two turns she should soften up the third alien bringing it down to 80 hp, allowing her to easily get the last shot on the second and the third aliens

Here are some of there other test cases:

Input

50 60 2

40 100

40 90

Output - 100

Input

50 60 2

40 100

40 200

Output - 200

Input

50 100 2

60 100

60 200

Output - 200

Input

50 400 2

60 100

190 200

Output - 0

Can someone verify if it is correct?

````
def main():
    inputString = input("")
    inputList = inputString.split(" ")
    ashaShot, amarShot, n = int(inputList[0]), int(inputList[1]), int(inputList[2])

    hp = []
    gold = []
    for i in range(n):
        hpThis, goldThis = input("").split()
        hp.append(int(hpThis))
        gold.append(int(goldThis))

    def dp(origHp, currAsha):
        if(all([i == 0 for i in origHp])):
            return currAsha
        firstAmarIndex = 0
        for index, i in enumerate(origHp):
            if(i>0):
                firstAmarIndex = index
                break
        # firstTemp = hp[firstAmarIndex]
        origHp[firstAmarIndex] = max(0, origHp[firstAmarIndex] - amarShot)
        maxAns = 0
        tempHp = origHp[:]
        for index, i in enumerate(origHp):
            if(i == 0):
                continue
            if(i<=ashaShot):
                temp = tempHp[index]
                tempHp[index] = 0
                maxAns = max(maxAns, gold[index] + dp(tempHp[:], currAsha))
                tempHp[index] = temp
            else:
                temp = tempHp[index]
                tempHp[index]-=ashaShot
                maxAns = max(maxAns, dp(tempHp[:], currAsha))
                tempHp[index] = temp
        
        maxAns = max(maxAns, dp(tempHp[:], currAsha))

        return maxAns

    maxAns = 0
    # asha takes a random shot
    tempHp = hp[:]
    for index, i in enumerate(hp):
        if(i<=ashaShot):
            temp = tempHp[index]
            tempHp[index] = 0
            maxAns = max(maxAns, dp(tempHp[:], gold[index]))
            tempHp[index] = temp
        else:
            temp = tempHp[index]
            tempHp[index]-=ashaShot
            maxAns = max(maxAns, dp(tempHp[:], 0))
            tempHp[index] = temp

        # asha skips her turn
    maxAns = max(maxAns, dp(tempHp[:], 0))
    print(maxAns)

main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this question with vanilla JS. Here is my code below

```
const spaceGame = class {
    constructor(ashaG, amarG, alianArr) {
      this.ashaG = ashaG;
      this.amarG = amarG;
      this.alianArr = alianArr;
      this.alianStrength = alianArr.map(c => c.p)
      this.pointsArr = [[0, 0]];
      this.predictionArray = [[...this.alianStrength]];
      this.predict();
    }
  
    personShoot(person) {

      // Get the person gun power
      const per=[this.ashaG, this.amarG];

      // Declare 2 empty array
      const resArr = [];
      const resPts = [];

      // Loop over prediction Array, arr is the small array inside prediction Array
      this.predictionArray.forEach((arr, j) => {
        
        // Make a new array y, by examining arr
        const y = arr.map((c, i) => {

          // Create a duplicate copy of arr
          let temp = [...arr];

          // Create duplicate copy of the points array
          const tempPoints = [...this.pointsArr[j]];

          // check if the num is greater than 0
          if (temp[i] > 0) {
            // Reduce alian power
            temp[i] = temp[i]-per[person];
            if(temp[i]<1){
              // If alian died, get the points
              tempPoints[person]= tempPoints[person]+this.alianArr[i].g
            }
          }else{
              // Remove duplicates from array to avoid stack over flow 
              temp = Array(1).fill(0)
          }
          // fill the empty arrays with data
          resPts.push(tempPoints)
          return temp;
        })
        resArr.push(y)
      })

      // Replace prediction and points array
      this.predictionArray = resArr.flat();
      this.pointsArr = resPts;
    }


    predict(){

      // See max value of prediction array
      const predictionArrMax = Math.max(...this.predictionArray.flat());

      // Recursion if there is something left
      if(predictionArrMax>0){
        this.task = !this.task;
        
        if(this.task){
          this.personShoot(0);
        }else{
          this.personShoot(1);
        };
        
        // console.log(this.pointsArr)
        // Call this funciton again
        setTimeout(w=>this.predict(),10)
      }
      else{
        // Output the value
        this.finalRes = Math.max(...this.pointsArr.map(e=>e[0]));
        console.log(this.finalRes)
        console.log('Final is called')
      }
    }
  
  }


const getResult = (ashaGun, amarGun, alianArr)=>{
  new spaceGame(ashaGun, amarGun, alianArr);
}


getResult(50, 400, [{ p:60, g: 100 }, { p: 190, g:200}])
```